# Laravel 5.5, Queued mail with attachments

Tags: laravel, queue, email-attachments

I want to send queued mail with attachments. When I test without queueing it works fine. 
But when I put mail in the queue the mail contains no attached files.
I see the file-paths in serialized string in the job

I get error Illegal string offset 'file'.

Any clues about whats wrong?

```
$attachments = [
    storage_path( 'app/pdf.pdf' ),
    storage_path( 'app/pdf-2.pdf' ),
];
dispatch( new ProcessReports( $this->report, $attachments ) )->delay( now()->addMinutes( 1 ) );
```

I use a mailable to setup mail:

```
$mailable = $this->subject( 'Your reports' )
                 ->view( 'email' );

if ( count( $this->attachments ) > 0 ) {
    foreach ( $this->attachments as $attachment ) {
        $mailable->attach( $attachment );
    }


}

return $mailable;
```

and finally the job handler:

```
public function __construct( Report $report, $attachments = array() ) {
    $this->report      = $report;
    $this->attachments = $attachments;
}

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle() {

        $email = new ReportSent( $this->report, $this->attachments );
        Mail::to( $this->report->user->email )
            ->send( $email );
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

**Controller**

```
$files = [
    public_path('files/160031367318.pdf'),
    public_path('files/1599882252.png'),
];

$details = [
    'title' => 'Mail from abc',
    'body' => 'hello',
    'email' => 'abc@gmail.com',
    'files' => $files
];
 
dispatch(new SendEmailJob($details));
```

**Job Handler**

```
public $details;

public function __construct($details)
{
    $this->details = $details;
}

public function handle()
{ 
  $details = [
    'title' =>  $this->details['title'],
    'body' =>$this->details['body'],
    'files' =>$this->details['files'],
    'email' =>$this->details['email'],
  ];
  Mail::to($this->details['email'])->send(new NotificationMail($details));   
 }
```

**Mailable**

```
 public $details;

 public function __construct($details)
 {
    $this->details = $details;
 }
 
 public function build()
 {
   $this->subject('Mail from abc')->markdown('mail.notification-mail');
    foreach ($this->details['files'] as $file){
       $this->attach($file);
    }

  return $this;
 }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).